# bootstrap Maga Menu in nopCommerce 3.70

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, nopcommerce

i am working on a nopCommerce 3.70 site, and i am making a custom MagaMenu dropdown,

the way i had it done was by creaing a TopMenu.cshtml file and i placed it under my themes folder, so its overriding the default, and i made some custom helpers and css based on bootstrap's Maga Menu, and for mobile i am still using the standard from DefaultClean, but my whole idea works only on the home page, all other pages is messed up the menu, i have no idea why its not working on the other pages, here is my code.

```js
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".dropdown").hover(
                function () {
                    $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop().fadeIn("fast");
                },
                function () {
                    $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop().fadeOut("fast");
                });
          
            $('.menu-toggle').click(function () {
                $(this).siblings('.top-menu.mobile').slideToggle('slow');
            });
            $('.top-menu.mobile .sublist-toggle').click(function () {
                $(this).siblings('.sublist').slideToggle('slow');
            });
        });
```

```css
         .navbar-default {
             color: #fff;
             background-color: #4ab2f1;
             border-color: #4ab2f1;
         }

        .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a { color: #fff; }

        .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a .caret {
            border-top-color: #fff;
            border-bottom-color: #fff;
        }

        .navbar-default .navbar-brand { color: #fff; }

        .menu-large { position: static !important; }

        .megamenu {
            padding: 20px 0px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .megamenu > li > ul {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .megamenu > li > ul > li { list-style: none; }

        .megamenu > li > ul > li > a {
            display: block;
            padding: 3px 20px;
            clear: both;
            font-weight: normal;
            line-height: 1.428571429;
            color: #333333;
            white-space: normal;
        }

        .megamenu > li ul > li > a:hover,
        .megamenu > li ul > li > a:focus {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #262626;
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
        }

        .megamenu.disabled > a,
        .megamenu.disabled > a:hover,
        .megamenu.disabled > a:focus { color: #999999; }

        .megamenu.disabled > a:hover,
        .megamenu.disabled > a:focus {
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: transparent;
            background-image: none;
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);
            cursor: not-allowed;
        }

        .megamenu.dropdown-header {
            color: #4ab2f1;
            font-size: 18px;
        }

        @media (max-width: 768px) {
            .megamenu {
                margin-left: 0;
                margin-right: 0;
            }

            .megamenu > li { margin-bottom: 30px; }

            .megamenu > li:last-child { margin-bottom: 0; }

            .megamenu.dropdown-header { padding: 3px 15px !important; }

            .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header { color: #fff; }
        }
```

```html
@model TopMenuModel
@using Nop.Web.Models.Catalog;

@helper RenderMegaMenuCategoryLine(CategorySimpleModel category, int level)
{
    <li class="dropdown menu-large">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="@Url.RouteUrl("Category", new {SeName = category.SeName})">

            @category.Name
            @if (category.NumberOfProducts.HasValue)
            {
                <text> </text>@T("Categories.TotalProducts", category.NumberOfProducts.Value)
            }
        </a>

        @{
            //subcategories
            var subCategories = category.SubCategories.Where(x => x.IncludeInTopMenu).OrderBy(m => m.Name).ToList();

            if (subCategories.Count > 0)
            {
                var itemsPerColumn = subCategories.Count();

                while (itemsPerColumn % 4 != 0)
                {
                    itemsPerColumn = itemsPerColumn + 1;
                }

                itemsPerColumn = itemsPerColumn / 4;

                var subCategoryColumn = new List<CategorySimpleModel>();
                var lastItem = subCategories.Last();

                
                <ul class="dropdown-menu megamenu row">
                    @foreach (var subCategory in subCategories)
                    {
                        subCategoryColumn.Add(subCategory);

                        if (subCategoryColumn.Count() == itemsPerColumn || subCategory.Equals(lastItem))
                        {
                            @RenderMegaMenuSubCategories(subCategoryColumn)

                            subCategoryColumn = new List<CategorySimpleModel>();
                        }
                    }
                </ul>
            }
        }
    </li>
}

@helper RenderMegaMenuSubCategories(List<CategorySimpleModel> categories)
{
    <li class="col-sm-3">
        <ul>
            @foreach (var category in categories)
            {
                <li>
                    <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Category", new {SeName = category.SeName})">

                        @category.Name
                        @if (category.NumberOfProducts.HasValue)
                        {
                            <text> </text>@T("Categories.TotalProducts", category.NumberOfProducts.Value)
                        }

                    </a>
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
    </li>
}

@helper RenderResponsiveCategoryLine(CategorySimpleModel category, int level)
{
    <li>
        <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Category", new { SeName = category.SeName })">
            @category.Name
            @if (category.NumberOfProducts.HasValue)
            {
                <text> </text>@T("Categories.TotalProducts", category.NumberOfProducts.Value)

            }
        </a>
        @{
            //subcategories
            var subCategories = category.SubCategories;

            var levelClass = "";
            if (level == 0)
            {
                levelClass = "first-level";
            }
            if (subCategories.Count > 0)
            {
                <div class="sublist-toggle"></div>
                    <ul class="sublist @levelClass">
                        @foreach (var subCategory in subCategories)
                        {
                            @RenderResponsiveCategoryLine(subCategory, level + 1)
                        }
                    </ul>
            }
        }
    </li>
}


@{

    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    @Html.Widget("header_menu_before")
                    @{
                        var rootCategories = Model.Categories.Where(x => x.IncludeInTopMenu).ToList();
                    }
                    @foreach (var category in rootCategories)
                    {
                        @RenderMegaMenuCategoryLine(category, 0)
                    }
                    @foreach (var topic in Model.Topics)
                    {
                        <li>
                            <a href="@Url.RouteUrl(" Topic", new {SeName = topic.SeName})">@topic.Name</a>
                        </li>
                    }

                    @Html.Widget("header_menu_after")
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


}

@{
    //mobile menu responsive

    var rootCategoriesResponsive = Model.Categories.ToList();
    //name it "Categories" if we have only categories. Otherwise, "Menu"
    var responsiveMenuTitle = (rootCategoriesResponsive.Count > 0 && Model.Topics.Count == 0) ? T("Categories") : T("Menu");
    <div class="hidden-lg hidden-md  menu-toggle">@responsiveMenuTitle</div>
    <ul class="hidden-lg hidden-md  top-menu mobile">
        @Html.Widget("mob_header_menu_before")
        @foreach (var category in rootCategoriesResponsive)
        {
            @RenderResponsiveCategoryLine(category, 0)
        }
        @foreach (var topic in Model.Topics)
        {
            <li><a href="@Url.RouteUrl(" Topic", new { SeName=topic.SeName })">@topic.Name</a></li>
        }
        @Html.Widget("mob_header_menu_after")
    </ul>

}
```

the code is all inside the TopMenu.cshtml page, and js is surrounded with script tags, and the css is  surrounded with script tags, and ofcourse i do the escape char for @media in the css.

anyone with input on that?

[image: nopCommerce 3.70 Maga Menu]

Comment: What is "messed up" about the menu?  Can you provide some pics?

Comment: i have updated with an image, as you can see the navbar is messed up, it should be identical to whats in this jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tstuxjhm/

Comment: And your homepage, it works fine?  Does your homepage use _ColumnsOne.cshtml as a layout?  I see from the picture the other pages are using _ColumnsTwo.

Comment: yes, the home page use _ColumnOne.cshtml, but they all render the TopMenu as a partial.

Comment: Right, I'm trying to figure out what's different between the pages.  Where do you include BootStrap?

Comment: i am using the DefaultClean theme, and it uses bootstrap, so its included at startup because its needed for the theme, so i have no need to include it again.

Comment: see answer - bootstrap is not included with nopCommerce by default.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104438/discussion-between-dan-orlovsky-and-sol-stein).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem with your menu is **you are not including Bootstrap**.

**No version of nopCommerce uses Bootstrap by default**, which is why whenever a new version is released developers release bootstrap-enabled themes, as found here:

[Default Clean Theme Bootstrap version (Free)](http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/37671/default-clean-theme-bootstrap-version-free.aspx)

You can either grab the above theme and incorporate your menu there, or include it in your theme yourself.  If you choose the latter approach, unzip bootstrap into the content folder of your theme.

Then, from the Shared folder of your theme, in the _Root.Head.cshtml file, add references to your bootstrap files, like so:

```
Html.AddScriptParts(ResourceLocation.Head, "~/Themes/THEMENAME/Content/BOOTSTRAPFOLDER/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js");
Html.AddCssFileParts(ResourceLocation.Head, "~/Themes/THEMENAME/Content/BOOTSTRAPFOLDER/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css");
```

I am currently working on a 3.70 Bootstrap theme myself -- this is the method I used to incorporate bootstrap.

Comment: Bingo! thank you so much for your effort and help, here is why i got my mistake, and thats the same reason why in the home page it worked, i had a slider plugin in the home page that used bootstrap, so it was loaded on the page, so i taught it loads on all pages, and the fact is its a plugin, and it was included only in the plugin view, so you were right, i forgot to look on the other pages if bootstrap is loaded, but now i will have an issue on the home page getting bootstrap two times.

Comment: Brilliant!  Which plugin is the slider?

Comment: @SolStein - check this solution: http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/38862/nopcommerce-how-to-check-if-current-page-is-homepage.aspx  Maybe check if you're on the homepage in _root.head, and if not include the BootStrap files?  Not sure if the controller is touched at that point, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: easiest and cleanest way, would be i just take out from the plugin the bootstrap, because it will load anyway since its included in the topMenu now. :) btw, thanks u so much for your effort in helping another guy you hardly even dont know :)

Answer (score 0):

Since version 3.80 `nopCommerce` uses Bootstrap for the admin area...

So simply add

```
Html.AppendScriptParts("~/Administration/Scripts/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js");
```

to `TopMenu.cshtml`

And have a look at [this responsive mega menu](http://websitesolved.co.uk/megametro-megamenu-upgrade).